# My text get flipped automaticly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So this is my code

```
public Transform target;
void Update()
{
    if (target != null)
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

this is suppose to look at the player under any state but some how it get my Text mesh gets fliped
how it looks in unity:

https://gyazo.com/6ae1b42508bbd6b8bcb168ca2cdeca28

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at it from behind?

Comment: no im not i flipped it all kind of ways i even made it a separate object to be sure

Comment: Are you sure the z-direction of the object containing the text isn't pointing behind the text? Please provide a screenshot of your hierarchy, with your text object selected.

Comment: it is behaving as expected. move it to an empty child and flip it

Comment: i already did that

Comment: Then please include the information/screenshot in your question as requested by me, since otherwise we're left guessing at your exact situation.

Comment: Does the problem happen if you comment out the `LookAt` code? Are you able to pan the camera around and look at the text from different degrees of rotation?

Comment: I'm at least 70% sure that this problem is caused due to the Text Mesh's forward vector pointing behind it rather than in front of it, which would cause any basic call to `LookAt` to make the text appear backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of lookAt

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - target.position);
```

Comment: @FatihTkale Great that you got an answer - please be sure to accept an answer if it satisfactorily solves your question (click the checkmark next to it). Though I admit I'm a bit dismayed that we didn't get sufficient information to diagnose with certainty what was going on.

Comment: @Serlite What I am assuming was happening that the `LookAt` method can't figure out where the front of the text is, so modifying only the Quaternion of the transform instead of only the transform component.